# How to iterate a function

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, parametric-functions, scoping

I have written a custom function called `f1[r_]` and I have tried iterating this function using `Table`. I work nicely for the first value and the error appears for the successive inputs. The error message states " Cannot compute all the singular vectors". What mistake I am doing.

```
L1 = 1;
ks = 2*^9;
z1 = L1/3;
z2 = 0.8*L1;

u1 = c[1] Cos[λ x] + c[2] Sin[λ x];
u2 = c[3] Cos[λ (x - z1)] + c[4] Sin[λ (x - z1)];
u3 = c[5] Cos[λ (x - z2)] + c[6] Sin[λ (x - z2)];
u = Piecewise[{{u1, x <= z1}, {u2, z1 <= x <= z2}, {u3, x > z2}}];

rodR = {{1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0, -1. λ Sin[0.2 λ], λ Cos[
      0.2 λ]}, {Cos[0.333333 λ], 
    Sin[0.333333 λ], -1., 0, 0, 
    0}, {5.*10^-10 K1 Cos[0.333333 λ] - 
     1. λ Sin[0.333333 λ], λ Cos[
       0.333333 λ] + 5.*10^-10 K1 Sin[0.333333 λ], 
    0, -1. λ, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Cos[0.466667 λ], 
    Sin[0.466667 λ], -1., 0}, {0, 0, 
    5.*10^-10 K2 Cos[0.466667 λ] - 
     1. λ Sin[0.466667 λ], λ Cos[
       0.466667 λ] + 5.*10^-10 K2 Sin[0.466667 λ], 
    0, -1. λ}};

rodP = FullSimplify[Det[rodR]]

comb = Tuples[{0.001*ks, (1*^12)*ks}, 2];
sub1 = comb[[1]]
rodvar = Table[c[i], {i, 1, 6}];
s5 = Flatten[λ /. 
   NSolve[(P /. {K1 -> sub1[[1]], K2 -> sub1[[2]]}) == 0 && 
     0 < λ < 30, Reals]]

f1[r_] := 
  Module[{m}, {uu, ww, vv} = 
    SingularValueDecomposition[
     rodR /. {K1 -> sub1[[1]], 
       K2 -> sub1[[2]], λ -> s5[[r]]}]; 
    NN = Last[Transpose[vv]]; sub1 = Flatten[{rodvar, λ}]; 
   sub2 = Flatten[{NN, s5[[r]]}]; 
   m = u /. Table[sub1[[i]] -> sub2[[i]], {i, 1, 7}]; Return[m]];

af1 = Table[f1[i], {i, 1, 2}]
```